# phantomjs not following redirects

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to get the response from the following URL:-

```
http://www.marriott.com/reservation/availabilitySearch.mi?isSearch=false&fromDate=06/25/2017&toDate=06/26/2017&clusterCode=&corporateCode=&groupCode=&numberOfRooms=1&numberOfGuests=1&incentiveType_Number=&incentiveType=false&marriottRewardsNumber=&useRewardsPoints=false&propertyCode=NYCCP
```

When I open this URL in a browser this URL redirects to:- `http://www.marriott.com/reservation/rateListMenu.mi`

and I get the desired output.  But when I try to get the resposne from  phantomjs I did not get the desired output.  I am using the below phantomjs code:-

```
var system = require('system');
var webPage = require('webpage');
var page = webPage.create();
var url = system.args[1];
page.settings.userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36';
page.settings.javascriptEnabled = true;
page.settings.loadImages = false;
phantom.cookiesEnabled = true;
phantom.javascriptEnabled = true;


page.viewportSize = {
    width: 1280,
    height: 720
};

page.open(url, function (status) {
    setTimeout(function () {
        console.log(page.content)
        phantom.exit();
    }, 10000);

});
```

I also tried increasing/decreasing timeout value but no luck.

Comment: I've tried your code and it return the desired page. `I did not get the desired output` What did you get instead?

Comment: `page.open(url, function (status) { console.log(status); }` <-- You should check status of request, it can be success or fail. It's important to check because maybe PhantomJS just couldn't access the target site (your IP could be banned or you misspelled the URL)

Comment: @Vaviloff Have you matched the response with the response of the browser? Is it exactly the same ?

Comment: @Vaviloff If you save the resposne given by the phantom in a html file and open it in a browser it will show you a page saying "Your session has expired." and this is not the desired output.

Comment: Your target site heavily relies on javascript. I doubt that opening page locally would work anyway, if you need search results you better parse them with javascript.

Comment: @Vaviloff opening page locally on a browser redirects correctly.  Why it is not working on phantomjs.  If phantomjs is a GUI less browser then it should also work on phantomjs.